# Is UPDATE the easiest way to change the most recent DATETIME entries in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im glad you are here !
:)

I have a table that is populated nightly from a bulk insert. job
The issue is that I need to to mark the most recent entries with the previous day's date

I have used getdate() -1 on other tables where I leverage select, so the data is changed before enterintg in to the table.

But how would i select from a table the most recent entries and change their value to the prior day's date.
I have not used UPDATE.. but it seems as if my example would be a good use case.

I don't know how to update only the desired (most recent) entries however.
I am concerned that I do not accidentally mark all the table entries with 1 day back.

Below is an example of the table structure. Any advice or example is greatly appreciated

[image: Table Sample]

Comment: You need to update a table, therefore you should use `update`. The alternatives are overkill: delete the records and re-insert them, or insert records and use conflict resolution

Comment: Exactly, `UPDATE` is used to change values.

Comment: I would ask why you need to change the dates of only "the most recent entries". This sounds like a design issue or an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: VIEW? Create a view where you change your date as you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need `update` in order to change the date values you want, but as you've stated, you do not want to "accidentally mark all the table entries with 1 day back."

So before you can write your `update` statement, you need to master a `select` statement that perfectly isolates the data. Then it is trivial to modify the `select` statement into an `update` statement.

But as you may have noticed, the "date" you are referring to is actually a `datetime` type, which contains a time component. So in order to easily refer to todays date, you need to disregard the time component. You can do this by casting the `datetime` into a `date` type.

Something like this:

```
select * from [your_table] where cast([DATE] as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
```

In order to refer to yesterday, use `dateadd` to "add" -1 days to today's date. Then your update would be something like this:

```
update [your_table] set [DATE] = cast(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as date) where cast([DATE] as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
```

Comment: This is a relatively simplified approach that does not consider edge cases like running the update statement at the stroke of midnight, the possibility that the [DATE] might be in a different time zone, etc, etc.

Comment: This works . Thank you ! The points mentioned above are things that i will review once the prototype is completed.